# The operator $T(x)(t) = \int_0^tx(s)ds$ doesn't have dense image

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to solve this problem:
Let $X = C[0,1]$ be the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with the uniform norm and define the bounded operator
$$T \colon X \to X$$ 
$(T(x))(t) = \int_0^t x(s)ds$. I need to prove that Im$(T)$ is not dense but I have not idea how to do it.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: $(T (x))(0) $ is always zero. (It is a deeper fact that the linear span of the image of T and the constant function $1$ is also not dense.)

Comment: @Ian: Er, I think the linear span of the image of $T$ and 1 *is* dense.  If $f$ is $C^1$ then $f(0) + T(f') = f$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus, and the $C^1$ functions are dense in $C([0,1])$.

Comment: Woops. I mixed up empty interior vs not dense for a moment.

Comment: Rather, I mixed up *meager* vs. not dense for a moment. Shame on me for commenting while tired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $[T(x)](0) = 0$ for all $x \in X$.